# How to get YouTube Channel Subscribers and set them in a recycler view like list view?

Tags: java, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm making an app where user can increase their channel subscribers by sub4sub. But problems is that I want get all subscribers list of user channel for verify that user subscribe or not. Question is this how I can get all subscribers of user channel.

But from this code I only get user channel id not getting user subscribers list.

One more questions I want put user channel I'd into hashmap
Please tell me how I can do.

I tried this

```
private class GetSubscriptionTask extends AsyncTask<Account, Void, List<Subscription>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Subscription> doInBackground(Account... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");
            try {
                GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                   LoginActivity.this,
                    Collections.singleton(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(params[0]);

                YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Get User's Own Channel")
                    .build();

                ChannelListResponse channelListResponse = youtube
                    .channels()
                    .list("id,contentDetails")
                    .setMine(true)
                    .setFields("items(contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads,id)")
                    .execute();

                // get signed user channel id:
                Channel myChannel = channelListResponse.getItems().get(0);
                String channelId = myChannel.getId(); // this is user's channel ID

                Log.d(TAG, "my youtube channel id: " + channelId);

                SubscriptionListResponse connectionsResponse = youtube
                    .subscriptions()
                    .list("snippet")
                    .setChannelId(channelId)
                    .execute();

                return connectionsResponse.getItems();
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getSubscription:recoverable exception"+userRecoverableException.getLocalizedMessage());
                startActivityForResult(userRecoverableException.getIntent(), RC_RECOVERABLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getSubscription:exception"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Subscription> subscriptions) {

            if (subscriptions != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "subscriptions : size=" + subscriptions.size());
                for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "subscription : " + subscription.getId());
                    displayToast(subscription.getId());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "subscriptions: null");
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```